# Можно ли с помощью Python скачать файл по ссылке, не зная имени и расширения файла

Tags: python

По подобной ссылке:

http://bla-bla.su/catalog/getfile/id/727243

с помощью браузера скачивается файл с именем **bla-bla.pdf**

Как можно скачать такой файл с помощью Python, именно с таким именем и расширением, не зная заранее ни имени файла, ни его расширения, и имея в распоряжении только ссылку?

Каким образом это делает браузер?

Comment: Браузер берёт имя файла из заголовка Content-Disposition.

Comment: @Voko вы можете добавить это как ответ на свой вопрос (кнопка "Ответить на собственный вопрос" ниже)

Comment: Некоторые cайты (и не только) содержат так называемые API, которые могут облегчить вам работу ! Попробуйте ознакомиться с самим сайтом и его API. Благодаря ему вы сможете не только качать неизвестные ( или известные :) ) вам файлы, но и творить еще много каких вещей

Comment: На русских именах файлов такой код выдаст странное

Comment: @andreymal  
[Решение проблемы с кириллическими именами файлов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1198813/%d0%94%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-content-disposition-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного запоздал, но вот функция, которая из Response (ответ от requests.get post и прочих) сделает имя файла. Можно сделать дополнительную проверку расширения на соответствие mime-типу, но мне было честно лень, поэтому как-нибудь сами. Спасибо.
Тут работает с расширениями, где первые два символа буквенные. Ну и все страшные %20 и прочие преобразуются в человекочитаемые штуки.

Конкретно за имя файла в вашем случае отвечает [content-disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8/Content-Disposition) со своим параметром filename. Но не всегда этот параметр присутствует, так что надо обрабатывать такие ситуации.

```
import requests
from mimetypes import guess_extension as extension
import re
from urllib.parse import unquote

def get_filename(response: requests.Response):
    headers = response.headers
    
    if "content-disposition" in headers and "filename" in headers["content-disposition"]:
        # если имя файла указано, то вернем его, предварительно его разкодировав из url-формата
        filename = re.match(r'.*filename=\"(.{1,})\".*').group(1)
        return unquote(filename)
        
    else: # тут мы обрабатываем тот случай, если сервер не передал имя файла
        
        url = response.url.split("?")[0] # у url отсекаем query-строку
        # http://example.com/abc.de/?lyalya=topolya -> http://example.com/abc.de/
        
        # теперь получим "имя". Может быть такое, что после него будет последним символом /
        # от него необходимо избавиться, что мы делаем с помощью rstip
        # http://example.com/abc.de/ -> http://example.com/abc.de
        
        filename = url.rstrip("/").split("/")[-1]
        # http://example.com/abc.de -> abc.de
        # проверяем наличие расширения файла у URL
        
        if re.findall(r'\.[a-zA-Z]{2}[\w]{0,2}$', filename):
            # если расширение присутсвует, то вернем то, что уже есть
            return unquote(filename)
        
        else: #если расширения нет, то добавим его самостоятельно
            # получим мы его благодаря сопоставлению mime-type
            
            # content-type содержит mime-type и charset. Получим только первый
            content_type = headers["Content-Type"]
            content_type = re.findall(r'([a-z]{4,11}/[\w\+\-\.]+)', content_type)[0]
            
            if "Content-Type" in headers and extension(content_type):
                filename = filename + extension(content_type)
                return unquote(filename)
                
            else: # если content-type не указан (такое вообще бывает?)
                # вернем как есть, страдайте сами
                return unquote(filename)
```

**Разберём несколько примеров**

*1) URL: https://bla.bla.su/getfile/id/12345, заголовок Content-disposition передан правильно*

- Алгоритм находит заголовок
- Находит в нём параметр filename
- Декодирует из URL-закодированного формата на всякий случай
- Возвращает декодированный параметр

*2) URL: https://bla.bla.su/getfile/id/12345, заголовок не содержит параметр filename, однако content-type содержит application/pdf*
Такое бывает при получении файлов от googleapis. наглядный пример на скачивании шрифтов с omahedesign - https://omahedesign.com/download-page/?d=eyJkb3dubG9hZF9pZCI6NTI1NH0 (не реклама, рабочий пример с редиректом на файл без расширения)

- Алгоритм не находит заголовок
- Удаляет query строку (её в нашем случае нет, но так бы удалил)
- Обрезает url до 12345 и записывает в filename
- Не находит здесь расширение файла (`re.findall(r'\.[a-zA-Z]{2}[\w]{0,2}$', filename)`)
- Смотрит Content-Type и видит там mime-type - application/pdf (может видеть там же ещё charset, который нас не сильно интересует в данном случае, поэтому мы его отсекаем)
- Сопоставляет mime-type и расширение через специальный встроенный модуль
- Получает из предыдущего шага ".pdf"
- Добавляет к filename найденное расширение ("12345" + ".pdf")
- Декодирует на всякий случай
- Возвращает человеческое имя 12345.pdf

*3) URL: https://bla.bla.su/getfile/id/12345.pdf, заголовок content-dispotition не содержит filename*

- Не находит нужного параметра в заголовке
- Так же отсекает и и вырезает 12345.pdf из url в filename
- Находит регулярным выражением расширение файла
- Декодирует filename
- Возвращает

*4) URL: http://example.com/file/lyalya-topolya.ver2/, заголовка content-disposition нет, а content-type содержит application/zip*

- Не находит filename в content-disposition
- Обрезает url до lyalya-topolya.ver2
- Находит расширение .ver2
- Возвращает декодированный filename `lyalya-topolya.ver2`

Что тут не так? А не так, что по факту это архив о чем говорит content-type, а ver2 совсем никакое не расширение, а просто обозначение версии файла (просто часть имени). Что делать? Можно проверять на наличие расширения в базе известных расширений (думаю, есть готовый списки расширений). Можно еще проверить через библиотеку mimetypes расширение (например, `".zip" in mimetypes.types_map` вернет True, если расширение .zip будет в их базе)

Comment: # тут мы обрабатываем тот случай, если сервер не передал имя файла

Правильно я понимаю, что в этом случае имя файла обязательно должно содержаться в самой ссылке?

Comment: @Volko Добавил разбор примеров в ответ. Это же может быть не имя, а любая строка. То есть он просто пытается взять хоть что-то из url. Вплоть до доменного имени, если ничего иного не указано

Comment: Если на сервере файл с именем на кириллице, то в content-disposition кракозябры. Хотя браузер нормально расшифровывает, и скачивает. Как расшифровать питоном эти кракозябры?

Answer (score 0):

Решение помог найти первый комментарий к вопросу. В моём конкретном случае рабочий код получился следующим (код не универсальный, не подойдёт для любых случаев):

```
import requests
import re

r = requests.get(link)
content_disposition = r.headers['content-disposition']
file_name = re.findall("filename=(.+)", content_disposition)[0]
```