# Декодирование кириллического имени файла из content-disposition в ответе сервера?

Tags: python, кодировка, requests

Как декодировать имя файла из content-disposition в ответе сервера, если это имя там задано на кириллице?
Вот по такой ссылке:
http://bla-bla.su/catalog/getfile/id/542445
браузером скачивается файл с именем:
"**Инструкция паспорт лампа версия 2.pdf**"

Как скачать этот файл питоном именно с таким именем?
У меня получается в headers['content-disposition']
имя файла задано вот таким образом:

> "Ð˜Ð½ÑÑ‚Ñ€ÑƒÐºÑ†Ð¸Ñ Ð¿Ð°ÑÐ¿Ð¾Ñ€Ñ‚ Ð»Ð°Ð¼Ð¿Ð° B2B Ð²ÐµÑ€ÑÐ¸Ñ 2.pdf"

Как расшифровать эту строку и получить имя файла на кириллице?
Как это расшифровывает браузер?

Comment: Во-первых, этот сервер нарушает стандарты, потому что использовать русские буквы в HTTP-заголовках запрещено. Во-вторых, логично предположить, что requests соблюдает стандарты и поэтому не в состоянии угадать, как правильно расшифровать некорректные данные (а как браузеры угадывают — загадка)

Comment: В третьих, может помочь что-то такое: `headers['content-disposition'].encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')`

Comment: Именно это и помогло:

content_disposition = headers['content-disposition'].encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')

Именно с такими кодировками. Не пришлось другие подбирать.